# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend') after upgrade vue to 3.x

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Today I upgrade my google chrome extension vue version to 3.x, when run the app, the google chrome extension popup console shows error like this:

```
commons1.js:13392 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')
    at Object../src/public/widget/index.js (commons1.js:13392)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.js:23)
    at Object../src/popup/st.js (commons1.js:12725)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.js:23)
    at Object../src/popup/app.js (commons1.js:12543)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.js:23)
    at Object../src/popup/index.js (commons1.js:12687)
    at __webpack_require__ (popup.js:23)
    at popup.js:163
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (popup.js:57)
```

I am searching from internet that knows that seems [vue 3 did not support using extend to load third party component](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/629). what should I do to fix this problem? Is it possible using the vue 3 code to do the same thing as vue 2? how to tweak my vue 2 code? This is the vue 2 code with extend looks like:

```
export default Vue.extend( {
  template ,
  data : ()=>({})
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In vue 3 there's no exported member called `Vue`, the right code that's equivalent for `Vue.extend` is :

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  template ,
  data : ()=>({})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like the [dumentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/):

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export


Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Create a file in src/plugins/vuetify.js with this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you got this error for toastr library this solution for u:**

The same issue got resolved for me when **i have imported jQuery before importing toastr library** in my build json.

```
So please import toastr library after jQuery
```