# Nuxt build error: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'nuxt' of 'this' as it is undefined

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I want to create a new Nuxt project and followed their instructions here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/installation. Basically just running `npm init nuxt-app@latest <project-name>`.

After going through the setup (in which I choose Tailwind as my UI of choice), I run `npm run dev` and it crashes while trying to build saying "Cannot destructure property 'nuxt' of 'this' as it is undefined."

Here is the full stack:

```
 FATAL  Cannot destructure property 'nuxt' of 'this' as it is undefined.                                                                                                                                                      15:22:52  

  at postcss8Module (node_modules\@nuxt\postcss8\dist\index.js:15:10)
  at installModule (/C:/Users/conmi/Documents/Personal/Katie's%20Website/katierose-photos/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:416:9)
  at async setup (/C:/Users/conmi/Documents/Personal/Katie's%20Website/katierose-photos/node_modules/@nuxtjs/tailwindcss/dist/module.mjs:186:7)
  at async ModuleContainer.normalizedModule (/C:/Users/conmi/Documents/Personal/Katie's%20Website/katierose-photos/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:167:5)
  at async ModuleContainer.addModule (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:239:20)
  at async ModuleContainer.ready (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:51:7)
  at async Nuxt._init (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:478:5)
```

I found not including `'@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'` in the buildModules in nuxt.config.js removes the error, but it does not create the tailwind config files I need. Also, the line causing the error in postcss8Module's index.js is `const { nuxt } = this`. For some reason `this` is undefined.

Comment: Use node v16 and try `npx create-nuxt-app my-new-project`, see if works better anyhow.

Comment: @kissu I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Something is wrong with your system then because that one should work flawlessly.

Comment: I succeeded to use Tailwind as advised by its documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi sorry doesn't have enough rep to comment on this, but just wanted to say this issue is also being tracked at
https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/9115 for Nuxt 2

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from the recent [Nuxt 3 Release](https://nuxt.com/v3) and is being tracked on the [create-nuxt-app Github](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/1018).

Create-nuxt-app is not compatible with Nuxt 3 yet. Therefore, for now, you have to install Nuxt 3 and Tailwind CSS manually:

```bash
npx nuxi init <project-name>
cd <project-name>
npm install
npm install @nuxtjs/tailwindcss --save-dev
```

Now you should be able to run your app as expected:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: OP didn't say that he wanted to use Nuxt3.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (for the moment)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

add it to your package.json

```json
 "resolutions": {
    "@nuxt/kit": "3.0.0-rc.13"
  }
```

Comment: Same comment as of here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74936551/nuxt-fatal-error-typeerror-cannot-destructure-property-nuxt-of-this-as-it-i#comment132244538_74937218

Answer (score 0):

I found [vstollen solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74504337/10962358) only partially worked for me, so had to make additional installs:

```
npm install nuxt@latest vue-router@latest vue@latest --save-dev
```

This will probably cause **index.vue** to complain about **vue.extend** so will need to update the script section.

I found the solution here: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend') after upgrade vue to 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70813636/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-extend-after)

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'IndexPage'
})
</script>
```

Your new project should then start correctly without errors.